# How to pipe awk output (with periodic, continuous input) to output file?

Tags: awk, pipe

I am trying to write a command that pipes the continuous output of a *free* command (run every second) to an awk command that parses a specific value (available free memory) and outputs this to a file with a timestamp. Here are my current attempts at the command:

```
free -mto -s 1 | awk '/Mem/ { print strftime("%r") "," $4 }' >>memOut
```

And alternatively, after a bit of Googling

```
free -mto -s 1 | awk '/Mem/ { print strftime("%r") "," $4 >>"memOut"}'
```

Each run produces empty files. Any suggestions or possibly different methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to flush the buffer to see something in `memOut` during the execution:

```
free -mto -s 1 | awk '/Mem/ { print strftime("%r") "," $4; fflush(stdout) }' >> memOut
```

Here's an alternative version:

```
while sleep 1; do sed -n "s/MemFree: */`date`, /p" /proc/meminfo; done >> memOut
```

Comment: This gave me the output file I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**For old versions of `awk` you may have to use `system("")`.**

Actually, `fflush(stdout)` is for only for recent versions of `awk` and `gawk`, as its only in the POSIX standard since December 2012.

```
free -mto -s 1 | awk '/Mem/ { 
    print strftime("%r") "," $4;
    system(""); # Flush output
}' >> memOut
```

Note that using `system("")` flushes every file descriptor, its [full description](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) is in the `gawk` manual, section "9.1.4 Input/Output Functions".

Answer (score 4):

On certain versions of `awk` (e.g. mawk 1.3.3) you need to add the `-W interactive` command line flag to enable unbuffered operation with pipes.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure that you are getting what you actually *want* and not what you specifically asked.

If you want to know available memory on the system for programs then this might be more suitable:

```
free -m -s 1 | awk '/buffers\/cache/ { print strftime("%r") "," $4; fflush(stdout) }' >> memOut
```

Mem line's Used column includes caches and buffers and in most cases when you want to monitor memory usage for given computer/task those should at least be noted.